# Proper name or term of comma thousandths grouping notation

Tags: notation, terminology

What is the proper name or terminology of notation for using a comma to separate and group thousandths of a number?

As in, formatting large numbers for readability:

```
comma delimited    real number
          1,000           1000
         10,000          10000
        100,000         100000
      1,000,000        1000000
```

How would you refer to this grouping of every third digit?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Thousand separation* or *digit grouping*.

Answer (score 0):

Perl users use the term "commify", probably a reference to "sub commify" in the Perl FAQ "How can I output my numbers with commas added?".